# How to translate @class forward declaration to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have in my AppDelegate in Objective-C.

```
@class PhoneViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UINavigationController *numberActivationFlow;
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *phoneFlow;
    IBOutlet PhoneViewController *phoneViewController;
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *configurationWizardFlow;
    IBOutlet UIViewController *configurationWizardFlowRoot;

    IBOutlet NumberActivationViewController *numberActivationViewController;

    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *captionNavigationItem;

    BOOL initialized;
    BOOL firstTimeExecCompleted;
    BOOL firstTimeActive;
    BOOL started;
    Activation* activation;
    Variant* variant;
}

+ (AppDelegate*) sharedInstance;
```

I am translating the above class to Swift and I wish to know how to translate the following line:

```
@class PhoneViewController;
```

Specially I have a problem the above code `@class PhoneViewController;`. How can I write in Swift because it is not a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reference Classes in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533989/how-do-i-reference-classes-in-swift)

Comment: Are you asking us to translate Objective-C code into Swift code or are you asking how to access properties of this Objective-C class from Swift code? Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you are asking and what issues you are having.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, Sorry for misunderstanding, to access properties of this Objective-C class from Swift code, I know how to do that I need to import in bridgeheadr. What I need to translate it if you can help me.

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question to clarify what you want. Your comment is still confusing but I think you are asking us to translate the code for you. This isn't a free code translation service. Make some attempt your self first. Update your question with your attempted Swift code and clearly explain what issues you are having with the translation. We are here to help, not do your work for you.

Comment: Dear  @rmaddy, I didn't ask you to work for me, I just asked how can I translate ` @class PhoneViewController;` in swift because it is not variable, if I knew that I wouldn't ask here, and if you don't know please don't comment let others answer the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## You Cannot always ignore the `@class` forward declarations if you do not own the code.

#### 'Bug' Report:

I work with an Objective-C library that is consumed as an opaque third-party framework, with only the header files exposed. When errors occur, the framework generates and vends a `MyError` object to a delegate. So far, so good.

Since the developer using the framework never creates an object of this class, it is **not** exposed, but no worries; since it is forward-declared, it's fine -- in ObjC! But Swift does not have Forward Declarations, and **the object was ignored in Swift files that rely on the ObjC framework.** In this case, no `MyError` object means no error reporting!

#### Workaround

I worked around the issue by redeclaring it in a Swift file, e.g. "MyError+Workaround.swift".

```
import Foundation

class MyError: NSError {} // the object actually is an NSError subclass
```

That's it. Hope this helps someone else out there.

#### Update

We fixed the code by explicitly adding the class in the umbrella header; coding contortions no longer needed.

Comment: Update: we fixed the code by explicitly adding the class in the umbrella header, coding contortions no longer needed.

Comment: How do you add what kind of file in the umbrella header?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified your question, the answer is simple. You simply ignore the `@class PhoneViewController` line when converting to Swift.

That is known as a forward declaration in Objective-C. It has no counterpart in Swift.